# How can I trigger a background fade in after an animation completion?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set a background to the parent element "banner".

How can I make this background fade in after the child elements "block" and "block2 finish animating and reveal the text underneath?

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="box bg">
          <!-- Start of intro animation container --->
          <div class="title">
            <!-- Start of main heading --->
            <span class="block"></span>
            <h1 class="home-header second-header">WORN WAX<span class="dot2">.</span></h1>
          </div>
          <!-- End of main heading --->
          <div class="role">
            <!-- Start of sub heading --->
            <div class="block2"></div>
            <p class="role-text project-type">WEBSITE BUILD / APP DESIGNS</p>
          </div>
          <!-- End of sub heading --->
        </div>
        <!-- End of intro animation container --->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set a background to the parent element"? As a background image or..

Comment: Hi, sorry this was unclear, I meant a background image. So a background image is applied to "banner", but I want this background image to fade in after the child elements "block" & "block2 have faded in.

Comment: There's no property like `background-image-opacity` so you'll need to restructure your HTML to have either an image that is positioned appropriately and target that or use a pseudo element like `:after` or `:before`.

Answer (score 0):

This nice CSS-only solution uses keyframe animation to get there. If you know how long the initial animation takes (I decided to use a fadein because I don't know what you want), you can use that as the delay to fade in the background. Be sure to place the background image on a pseudo-element, because lowering the opacity means everything inside the element is also invisible, including its children `.title` and `.role`

```css
.home-header,
.project-type {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkred;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

.box.bg {
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.box.bg::after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  /* Delay until after the block animations */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s ease 2s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s ease 2s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s ease 2s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s ease 2s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s ease 2s;
}

# Based on https: //stackoverflow.com/a/11681331/5015356
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="box bg">
          <!-- Start of intro animation container --->
          <div class="title">
            <!-- Start of main heading --->
            <span class="block"></span>
            <h1 class="home-header second-header">WORN WAX<span class="dot2">.</span></h1>
          </div>
          <!-- End of main heading --->

          <div class="role">
            <!-- Start of sub heading --->
            <div class="block2"></div>
            <p class="role-text project-type">WEBSITE BUILD / APP DESIGNS</p>
          </div>
          <!-- End of sub heading --->

        </div>
        <!-- End of intro animation container --->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```